# How to have a long and wide table stretch over multiple pages?

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking, tabularx, sidewaystable

I have a big table generated from Stata software. I am trying to fit width of the table and have the table to stretch over multiple pages. I assume we can shrink the width a little bit to fit the width of the table in each page, but I was not sure how to have the table to be split over multiple pages.

```
\begin{table}[!h]
 \caption{Test}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllll}
\cline{1-13}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{4} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{5} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{6} \\
\cline{1-13}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{A} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}a} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.657} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.636} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.943} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.971} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{*} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.419} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.819} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.396)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.475)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.583)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.969)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.428)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.522)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}b} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.499} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.480} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.519} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.165} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.084} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.505} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.379)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.475)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.440)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.635)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.422)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.509)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}c} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.073} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{2.026} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.089} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.133} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.176} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.424} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.643)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(1.052)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.641)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.975)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.543)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.695)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}d} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.155} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.011} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.134} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.325} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.469} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.989} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.344)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.421)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.448)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.609)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.431)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.526)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}a} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.672} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.998} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{*} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.995} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.479} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.378} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.173} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.641)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.837)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.810)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(1.089)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.553)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.612)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}b} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.166} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.363} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.032} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.051} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.718} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.392} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.676)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.890)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.888)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(1.453)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.604)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.625)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}c} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.778} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.818} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.668} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.305} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.766} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.864} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.617)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.800)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.755)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(1.073)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.513)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.570)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
%%%%%
\cline{1-13}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Changing `tabular` to [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) will probably be the most straight forward adjustment, although you will need to do more than that also depending on document class . Unrelated but STATA seems to have one of the worst converter to LaTeX--your table is going to need a lot of cleaning. Consider converting data to `R` and use export to LaTeX using [kableExtra](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/1.3.4).

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{showframe}% only for demo
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lllllllllllll}
    \caption{Test}\\\cline{1-13}
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{2} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{3} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{4} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{5} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{6} \\
        \cline{1-13}
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{A} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}a} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.657} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.636} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.943} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.971} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{*} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.419} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.819} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.396)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.475)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.583)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.969)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.428)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.522)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}b} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.499} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.480} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.519} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.165} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.084} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.505} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.379)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.475)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.440)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.635)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.422)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.509)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}c} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.073} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{2.026} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.089} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.133} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.176} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.424} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.643)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(1.052)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.641)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.975)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.543)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.695)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}d} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.155} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.011} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.134} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.325} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.469} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.989} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.344)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.421)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.448)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.609)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.431)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.526)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{B} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}a} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.672} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.998} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{*} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.995} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.479} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.378} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.173} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.641)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.837)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.810)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(1.089)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.553)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.612)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}b} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.166} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.363} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.032} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-1.051} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.718} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.392} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.676)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.890)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.888)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(1.453)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.604)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.625)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\hspace{1em}c} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.778} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.818} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-2.668} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-3.305} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.766} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.864} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.617)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.800)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.755)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(1.073)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.513)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.570)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
        %%%%%
        \cline{1-13}
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]